# Why does Dr. Parnassus keep making deals and wagers?

Tags: character, analysis, the-imaginarium-of-doctor-parnassus

in The Imaginarium of Doctor Parnassus, Parnassus makes several deals or wagers with Mr. Nick, who is supposed to be a personification of the devil.  However, we learn that most of the deals made with Mr. Nick, even when won, usually don't have a good ending.

For example, Parnassus became immortal and young again after a deal with Mr. Nick; however, in exchange he had to hand over any kids he had at the age of 16.  So, while the deal may seem good to begin with, it still had a bad result.

And yet, Parnassus never learns to not take these deals.  Why?

Comment: It's a great question.  Been years since I've seen this movie, but the relationship you mention, as well as the Tom Waits casting choice, was extremely compelling.  Possibly Dr. P. is a gambling addict, always thinking he can get the better of the Devil next time around.  It's about the adrenaline of the bet more than the outcome.  (I'd have to re-watch to give a definitive answer though.)

Comment: Exactly, as @DukeZhou said - Parnassus was a gambling addict. It's pretty clear in the movie, Mr. Nick even states it himself.

Answer (score 1):

Because he doesn't want to lose his soul; the more souls he can collect from other people and give to the devil in lieu of his own, the better (that's what I believe, at least).